# in C# a string member of a class failes to be accessed and the IDE throws an error without explaination

Tags: c#

The squiggly red line does not explain what is wrong with this simple code.

[image]

[image]

making the "Name" menber static allows the code to be compiled then why is it that it fails in a similar instantiation of the class?

[image]

Comment: Try `mystring.Name` instead. In your code you are trying to use the property as if it is defined as static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just make a mistake of using incorrect variable name instead of `Mystring` you need to use `mystring` name